# Calling function from a class

Tags: swift

I am trying to become confident using functions. I am practicing with the code below.

```
class Arithmetics {
var operand1: Double
var operand2: Double

init(operand1: Double, operand2: Double) {
    self.operand1 = operand1
    self.operand2 = operand2
    }    
func AddInsideClass(operand1: Double, operand2: Double) -> Double {
    var sum = operand1 + operand2
    return sum
    }
}

func AddOutsideClass(operand1: Double, operand2: Double) -> Double {
    var sum = operand1 + operand2
    return sum
    }

println(AddOutsideClass(5.5, 4.5))
println(Arithmetics.AddInsideClass(5.5, 4.5))
```

In the last 2 lines I tried to call the functions and output them on the console. The first println() is calling the function from outside the class, which works fine.
The second println() however gives me an error message that goes like this:

"stdin:23:35: error: extra argument in call
println(Arithmetics.AddInsideClass(5.5, 4.5))
^ ~~~"

**What's the problem here?**

Is it because I cannot simply call a class method directly? Or can I call class methods only via a class instance like below?

```
var operation1: Double = Arithmetics.AddInsideClass(5.5, 4.5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

**First** – using your syntax – you declare the function as static and you can omit the variables and the `init` function

```
class Arithmetics {

  static func addInsideClass(operand1: Double, operand2: Double) -> Double {
    var sum = operand1 + operand2
    return sum
  }
}
```

You can call it on the class (the second parameter name is mandatory)

```
Arithmetics.addInsideClass(5.5, operand2:4.5)
```

**Second** you create an instance of the class which now needs no operands in the `add` function because they are set in the `init` function.

```
class Arithmetics {
  var operand1: Double
  var operand2: Double

  init(operand1: Double, operand2: Double) {
    self.operand1 = operand1
    self.operand2 = operand2
    }

  func addInsideClass() -> Double {
    var sum = operand1 + operand2
    return sum
    }
}
```

And the syntax to call it is

```
let operation1 = Arithmetics(operand1: 5.5, operand2: 4.5)
operation1.addInsideClass()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot vadian, the second option was, what I was looking for! :) Will need to further read tutorials to understand what you did in option 1. I don't know what this static means yet.

Answer (score 0):

> A class method is a method that operates on class objects rather than
>   instances of the class.

`AddInsideClass` is not a class-method. It can only be called using an object of the class `Arithmetics` and not with the class name itself.

Create an object of the class `Arithmetics` in order to call its methods in another class.

```
let arithmeticsClassObj = Arithmetics()
println(arithmeticsClassObj.AddInsideClass(5.5, 4.5))
```

Reference: [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassMethod.html)